# Is there an iOS wallpaper similar to Nexus Revamped?

Tags: ios, wallpaper

This is [Nexus Revamped](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stealthcopter.nexusrevamped&hl=en). Basically, it creates particles on the screen when users touch it.

I want to make an animated wallpaper: [a kaleidoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleidoscope#History) that spins when the user swipes on the screen.

Comment: If you want to make this a software-recommendation, please edit it to show you're looking to jailbreak and run existing mods. If it's really about API/SDK/coding - then SO is the place for this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible with iOS.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 thanks by the way, but I want to know why, and how?

Comment: Apple doesn't open up wallpaper access to developers, it may change in the future, but for now you just can't.